# Error: "XXX" Requires a provisioning profile

Tags: fastlane

so boggling with Fastlane for 1 week now i got nothing but errors.

By opening XCode and setting the Profile manually makes the build succeed. But there isn't much point to automation if there are manual steps.

My Fastfile looks like this:

```
default_platform(:ios)

platform :ios do
  desc "Build project"
  lane :beta do
    update_info_plist(
        plist_path: "./info.plist",
        app_identifier: "com.skinke.app"
    )
    cert
    sigh(adhoc:true)
    gym(
        export_options:{
            method:"ad-hoc",
            provisioningProfiles:{
                #"com.skinke.app" => "AdHoc_com.skinke.app.mobileprovision" ## nope
                "com.skinke.app" => "com.skinke.app AdHoc" ## also nope
            }
        }
    )
  end
end
```

So I've had no luck getting Gym to pick up the provisioningprofile. I suspect the error actually originates from XCode, but gym should have injected it right?

My intention is once this is successful i need to automate pushing to a USB connected iPad.

As a side question: There doesn't happen to be a dedicated tech support somewhere?

Comment: Have you looked into using [match](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/match/)? This will automate pretty much everything about this.

Comment: yes, and it's getting good, working provisioning profiles. But it's not setting the automatically in xcode. So i have to first run match, and then pick the match profile manually in xcode for it to work. I set up a local git with "git init /User/MyMac/Desktop/Testproject/fastlane/myprofiles" but it's all the same.

Comment: _match_ does set a variable that further builds (with _gym_ or other build actions from fastlane) will use. You shouldn't need to do anything else.